# Update syntax error in the WHERE clause

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Generating a Report from Query; capturing data from several tables. The Report has two calculated boxes and I want to `UPDATE` the data back to one of the tables. Debugging shows I'm capturing the variables but keeps giving me Syntax errors in the `WHERE` clause. I've tried lots of syntax iterations from scouring the net.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
Dim sqls As String
Dim TEP As Single
Dim PPS As Single
Dim RecipeN As String
TEP = Reports![RecipeBuild]![txtTEP]
PPS = Reports![RecipeBuild]![txtPPS]
RecipeN = Reports![RecipeBuild]![RecipeName]
sqls = "Update [tblRecipeBuild] " _
    & "Set TEP = " & TEP & " " _
    & "Set PPS = " & PPS & " " _
    & "WHERE [RecipeName] = '" & RecipeN & "';"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL sqls
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

An Access SQL `UPDATE` should include the `SET` keyword only once.

When you want to update more than one field, use `SET` once, and then use a comma between the pairs of *FieldName=Value* segments.

```vb
sqls = "Update [tblRecipeBuild] " _
    & "Set TEP = " & TEP & ", PPS = " & PPS & " " _
    & "WHERE [RecipeName] = '" & RecipeN & "';"
```

I think that should work but suggest you consider a parameter query instead of concatenating values into an `UPDATE` statement.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strUpdate As String
strUpdate = "UPDATE tblRecipeBuild SET TEP=pTEP, PPS=pPPS WHERE RecipeName=pRecipeN;"
Debug.Print strUpdate
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strUpdate)
With qdf
    .Parameters("pTEP").Value = TEP
    .Parameters("pPPS").Value = PPS
    .Parameters("pRecipeN").Value = RecipeN
End With
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and feedback. I'm fairly new to the Access/Database world (lots of VBA experience in Excel) but really enjoy learning the 'why' behind the functions. I will research and try to understand why you recommend the parameter query angle.